# Почему nginx не отображает список файлов в директориях?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Никак не пойму, в чем может быть проблема.

Есть задача с помощью Nginx опубликовать несколько файлов. Однако, список директорий показывается, а файлов нет, при этом в error.log nginx это:

```
2018/05/30 07:33:38 [crit] 22491#22491: *1 stat() "/site/RPMS/file.txt" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 146.120.119.127, server: 35.207.49.222, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "35.207.49.222", referrer: "http://35.207.49.222/"
```

Что делал: взял centos7, поставил на него nginx,

```
    cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  35.207.49.222;
    root /site/RPMS;

    location / {
        autoindex on;
   }
}
```

Права на директории и файлы пытался пофиксить, сейчас стоят 755

```
namei -om /site/RPMS/file.txt


f: /site/RPMS/file.txt
  dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
  drwxrwxrwx nginx nginx site
  drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx RPMS
  -rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx file.txt
```

Но, если мы зайдем на http://35.207.49.222/ увидим, что файлов нет и http://35.207.49.222/file.txt показывает 403 Forbidden, хотя файл есть.

Процесс работает от nginx

```
ps aux | grep nginx
root     22490  0.0  0.1  46404   960 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx    22491  0.0  0.3  46788  2156 ?        S    07:33   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Что еще можно попробовать пофиксить, чтобы nginx показывал файлы?

Comment: selinux или что-нибудь в этом духе? начните с `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: Просто рукалицо))) Нужно было ребутнуться после выключения selinux.